# How to Collapse and Expand sharepoint list using js

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I have one checkbox if i check it collapse the shrepoint list, if i uncheck it it should expand all how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to hide it you can use JavaScript to add the hide style to it.

```
function checkboxHandler() {
    var el = document.getElementById('yourCheckBoxId');
    if(el.value){
       document.getElementById('sharePointId').setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
    }else{
       document.getElementById('sharePointId').setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');
    }
}
```

If you were to use a nice JavaScript library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) you can make this code simpler and add some sweet animations.